# Android circle not rotating from center?

Tags: java, android, mobile, geometry

I can't get the circle rotate around its center.

Here is my xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="15.0dip"

    <FrameLayout
        android:padding="0.0dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0.0dip">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/wheel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/wheel" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/centre"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/centre" />

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is a screenshot of what happens:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQwrf.png)

As you can see from the image, the circle is not center and it doesn't rotate around the center. The circle also gets pushed ofscreen

and here is my java:

```
public class MainActivity
    extends Activity
    implements View.OnTouchListener {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    ImageView circleView;
    double currentRotationDegrees;
    double cx;
    double cy;
    float mPreviousX;
    float mPreviousY;
    private Matrix rotationMatrix;

    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.circleView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.wheel);
        this.circleView.setOnTouchListener((View.OnTouchListener) this);
        this.circleView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
        if (this.rotationMatrix == null) {
        this.rotationMatrix = new Matrix();
        }
        this.rotationMatrix.reset();
        this.currentRotationDegrees = 0.0;
    }

/*
 * Enabled aggressive block sorting
 */
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        this.cx = (double)this.circleView.getWidth() / 2.0;
        this.cy = (double)this.circleView.getHeight() / 2.0;
        float f = motionEvent.getX();
        float f2 = motionEvent.getY();

        Log.d((String)"MainActivity", (String)("Got x: " + f + " and y: " + f2));
        switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {

            case 1: {
                Log.d((String)"MainActivity", (String)("Current rotation degrees = " + this.currentRotationDegrees));
                double d = this.currentRotationDegrees % 30.0;
                Log.d((String)"MainActivity", (String)("Rotation modulus = " + d));
                if (d == 0.0) break;
                double d5 = d < 15.0 ? -1.0 * d : 30.0 - d;
                this.rotationMatrix.postRotate((float)d5, (float)this.cx, (float)this.cy);
                this.circleView.setImageMatrix(this.rotationMatrix);
                this.currentRotationDegrees -= d;
            }

            case 2: {
                Log.d((String)"MainActivity", (String)"Calculating rotation..");
                double d = (double)f - this.cx;
                double d2 = Math.atan2((double)f2 - this.cy, d);
                double d3 = (double)this.mPreviousX - this.cx;
                double d4 = Math.toDegrees(d2 - Math.atan2((double)this.mPreviousY - this.cy, d3));
                Log.d((String)"MainActivity", (String)("Rotation degrees: " + d4));
                this.rotationMatrix.postRotate((float) d4, (float) this.cx, (float) this.cy);
                this.circleView.setImageMatrix(this.rotationMatrix);
                this.currentRotationDegrees = d4 + this.currentRotationDegrees;
            }
            default: {
                break;
            }

        }

        this.mPreviousX = f;
        this.mPreviousY = f2;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace this code.

```
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0.0dip">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_camelot_wheel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/wheel" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_camelot_arrows"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/centre" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in your xml ,LinearLayout is in your circle outside,and you set LinearLayout's layout_margin. If you want to get the circle rotate around its center, you should get LinearLayout.s width and it's margin and divide by 2.

Comment: could you please provide the code to make your answer more clear?